# 8-partition of a planar convex body by 4 concurrent lines

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, plane-geometry, planar-partitions

It is known<sup>1</sup> that any convex body $K$ in the plane can be
partitioned into $6$ equal-area pieces by $3$ concurrent lines
which meet at a point in $K$.
Call this a *$6$-partition*.
This result cannot be extended to $8$-partitions (by $4$ concurrent lines):
A triangle cannot be $8$-partitioned (again, by $4$ concurrent lines meeting
at a point inside the triangle).<sup>2</sup>

My question is:

> ***Q***. Which convex bodies $K$ admit an $8$-partition? 
>   Are there natural necessary geometric constraints on $K$? 
>   Ideally, a characterization of such $K$?

Although an $8$-partition seems to require a quite symmetric $K$,
one can form a non-centrally symmetric $K$ that can nevertheless
can be $8$-partitioned, by arranging "bump-outs" on a regular $n$-gon
to break symmetries:

---

[image: OctAsymm]

          

<sup>An $8$-partition of a convex polygon with no evident symmetries.
Each octant contains one "bump-out."</sup>

---

[image: BumpOut]

          

<sup>Enlargement of each "Bump-out" above.</sup>

---

Of course the natural generalization to ***Q*** is: 
What can be said about $k$-partitions, $k>6$?

---

<sup>1</sup>
Buck, Robert C., and Ellen F. Buck. "Equipartition of convex sets." *Mathematics Magazine* 22, no. 4 (1949): 195-198.
Cited in: 
Berele, Allan, and Stefan Catoiu. "Nonuniqueness of sixpartite points."  *American Mathematical Monthly* 125, no. 7 (2018): 638-642.

<sup>2</sup>
Guardia, Roser, and Ferran Hurtado. "On the Equipartitions of Convex Bodies and Convex Polygons." In *EuroCG*, pp. 47-50. 2000.

Comment: If a body has a 180-degree rotational symmetry about a point, then it can be k-partitioned for any even k.  And maybe the converse holds too?